# Ctor parameter not being resolved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I am really stumped by this one. I understand the err msg but can't find anything wrong.

The message is:

---

None of the constructors found with 'Public binding flags' on type 'My Controller Object' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Services.Video.IVideoService videoService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(...list of the parameters in the constructor...

---

So as I understand this message the controller cannot resolve the videoService parameter...i.e. invoke it.

My service is very simple right now. Just started creating it.

```
public partial interface IVideoService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all videos
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Videos</returns>
    IList<Videos> GetAllVideos();

}
```

Interface implementation

```
public VideoService(ICacheManager cacheManager, IRepository<Videos> videoRepository, IRepository<VideoCategories> videoCategoryRepository, IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
{
    this._cacheManager = cacheManager;
    this._videoRepository = videoRepository;
    this._videoCategoryRepository = videoCategoryRepository;
    _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
}

public virtual IList<Videos> GetAllVideos()
{
     var query = _videoRepository.Table
     .Join
     (
         _videoCategoryRepository.Table,
         v => v.Id,
         vc => vc.Id,
         (v, vc) => new { Videos = v, VideoCategories = vc }
     )
     .Select(vid => vid.Videos);

     return query.ToList();
 }
```

Constructor of controller (abbreviated it is very long):

```
public MyController(ICategoryService categoryService, IVideoService videoService,.....)
{ ...code }
```

I have cleaned & rebuilt, closed VS & reopened. I can't figure out why it is not resolving. Intellisense is working and resolving everything perfectly but run time can't find it????

If other code needs to be included just let me know and I'll get it in there.

Thank You

Comment: Did you register all dependencies on the container that `VideoService` need to be constructed?

Comment: Yes & no. I have other services and they work just fine so no I didn't register any dependencies assuming they were already there.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot to do the builder.Register....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you forgot to register some dependencies from `VideoService`, for sample:

```
builder.RegisterType<EventPublishier>().As<IEventPublisher>();

builder.RegisterType<CacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>();
```